# How to disable blur effect on textures with OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I am using Texture-Mapped fonts in my OpenGL program.
I have drawn very basic fonts in a bitmap (each letter is 5x7 pixels, white on black background).
When displayed on a quad that makes more than a few pixels large, OpenGL is making some work to make the image smooth.
Is there an easy way to temporarily get rid of that blur effect ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try `glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST )`.