# Scale All Graphics in an OpenGL Game

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm just beginning with OpenGL and LWJGL, but I have experience in Java and game development. My game I'm making is going to be a 2D Pixel Art Platformer, with most sprites being 16x16px.

I want to scale all the graphics being rendered up by 3. In regular Java, you would draw all the pixels to a BufferedImage, and then draw that image by doing something like this:

```
g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
```

I'm trying to do the same with `glScalef()`, but it makes the images blurry, can I fix that or is there a better way to do it? Here's my code:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0, WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0, 1, -1);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glScalef(SCALE, SCALE, SCALE);
```

Please let me know of any other information I may need to provide.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the texture is being filtered. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3841028/4255187) to a similar question changes the default value of `GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER` from `GL_LINEAR` to `GL_NEAREST` with the following snippet:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. I guess it's now using the nearest neighbour filter to scale it. Thanks!